# Application Insights Logs Analysis

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight, azure-application-insights, bigdata

I have Event logs of Application Insights where events are logged and stored as json in text files stored in a blob storage. I need to find those jsons where a customProperty meets a criteria. The number of hit jsons are very less (around 10 or 20), however the data logged is very large. Any suggestions how this can be accomplished efficiently?

I have read in Microsoft documentation that HDInsights understand blob storage and is efficient. Is this relevant in my scenario? If so, could someone provide some starting points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDInsight, being a Hadoop-compliant implementation, is a good technology for logs analysis. It is [being stated](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-telemetry/) on the AppInsighs page about telemetry as well.
"On larger scales, consider HDInsight - Hadoop clusters in the cloud. HDInsight provides a variety of technologies for managing and analyzing big data."

On the same page, you may find the information about continuous export of AppInsights telemetry into the Azure Blobs storage.

Next step could be to use HDInsight for the analysis of that, but it will need you to implement some kind of algorithm.

For uploading the data to the HDInsight from Azure Blob you may see [that link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-upload-data/) (and [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage/) for querying).

For understanding on the logs processing pipeline, which is a common task for Hadoop/HDInsight, some walkthroughs and manuals are available, for example [this](http://hadooptutorial.info/log-analysis-hadoop/). But you will need to adjust this algorithm to your scenario.

Comment: To work with Application Insights from HDInsight, you first need to export the logs to blob storage. This has to be blob storage that HDInsight has been configured to be able to see. Then, you need some way to tell HDInsight about the document structure. Happily, if you use Spark on HDInsight, it can figure out the JSON structure on its own.

Comment: There's now a document at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-spark-analyze-application-insight-logs/ that provides some guidance and examples on doing this with Spark on HDInsight.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Application Insights there is another option. New analytic tool **Application Insights Analytics** has been introduced.

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2016/03/28/introducing-application-analytics

This tool also alows you to work with all logged data using the specific language:

```
requests
| where timestamp >= ago(24h)
| summarize count() by client_CountryOrRegion
| order by count_ desc
```

You can export data you need.